# What does "the establishment favorite" mean in this context?

Tags: sentence-meaning

I don't quite understand the part in bold from this long sentence.

> The 65-year-old lawmaker, who recently had been encouraged by President Donald Trump to seek a third term, made the surprise announcement hours before a showdown vote in an Alabama Senate runoff in which **the establishment favorite lost to firebrand Judge Roy Moore**.

[The source](https://www.yahoo.com/news/gop-sen-corker-announces-wont-seek-election-200626942--politics.html)

Comment: What precisely is it you do not understand?

Comment: ok, what's "the establishment favorite" ? and also not sure 'lost to'

Comment: *The establishment favorite* is the candidate favored by the *establishment*--the people in power. (In this case *the establishment* is the people who lead the national Republican party.) Sen. Strange lost, and *to* designates the candidate who won, Judge Moore.

Comment: Just mull it over. I would have understood it originally if it put as "the establishment's favorite" or "the favorite of the establishment". To me, establishment is not attributive, but possessive. It's just like saying "their favorite". Am I getting it right? Does "the establishment's favorite" or "the favorite of the establishment" sound ok? What would be the idiomatic usage?

Comment: Nouns are often employed in attributive position to designate agents, patients or other semantic complements. In this context consider 'party favorite', 'Senate favorite', 'teen favorite' = the person favored by the party, by the Senate, by teens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you are correct that *establishment's favorite* seems more grammatical, in English it's not uncommon to create [*compound nouns*](http://www.gingersoftware.com/content/grammar-rules/nouns/compound-nouns/) by joining together two (or more) nouns:

> ice cream
>
> jelly bean
>
> washing machine

and so on.  Sometimes these are joined together (policeman) and sometimes kept separate (automobile dealership).

In general, you can assume the compound is whatever the final noun is, modified by the previous nouns.  For example a "water distribution network" is a *network* (of pipes, pumps, valves, etc.) used to *distribute water*.  In the same way the "establishment favorite" is the *favored option* of the *established political party*.

Again these kind of nouns are so common you probably don't even notice you're reading this on your *computer screen* while typing on your *key-board* while signals go back and forth over your *network connection*.  You can even make up your own, once you get the hang of it.

Comment: I got it. But, apparently, there are also some cases that you should use the form of 's or of, instead of attributive nouns. For example, Tom's book, you wouldn't say Tom book, would you? That said, there got to be some rules that define when should use as an attributive or possessive. That's why I was just curious if establishment's favorite is correct, because I've seen 'my favorite', 'their favorite' and maybe 'Tom's favorite'. Can we say 'Tom favorite' in this case?

Comment: I can understand 'washing machine' makes sense, because that machine is used to wash sth. It should be an attributive, not possessive. The same thing for ice cream and jelly bean.

Comment: @dan actually we do sometimes use proper nouns + novel/movie/etc, for example "I'm reading yet another Stephen King novel", or, "that's a Tom Cruise movie".   In any language, past a certain point there are no "rules", only "conventions".

Comment: In this case the convention is that the named person should be famous enough that the listener should know who they are and recognize their relationship to the noun.  "That recipe is a Gordon Ramsay favorite" would be fine, but "That recipe is an Andrew favorite" sadly, would not.

Comment: ok, then. I know language is all about idiomatic and conventions. That's why it's hard to learn as a second language.